# 0-1 Knapsack optimization problem

Tags: optimization, knapsack

[image: knapsack problem]

**Can anyone explain how the writer rewrite the objective function in (7) to be written as (8)?**

Comment: I deleted my "answer" (which was supposed to be a comment to Rob Pratt's answer). Please accept his answer rather than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just consider the two cases:

- If $z_i=0$, the LHS and RHS are both $0$.
- If $z_i=1$, the LHS and RHS are both $p_i$.

Explicit calculations for the RHS:
\begin{align}
\theta_i \left(1 - \left(\frac{\theta_i-p_i}{\theta_i}\right)^0 \right)
&= \theta_i \left(1 - 1\right) = 0 \\
\theta_i \left(1 - \left(\frac{\theta_i-p_i}{\theta_i}\right)^1 \right)
&= \theta_i \left(1 - 1 + \frac{p_i}{\theta_i}\right) = \theta_i \cdot \frac{p_i}{\theta_i} = p_i
\end{align}